# Neo4j Cypher reduce DB hits for supplemental node

Tags: neo4j, cypher

This is a part of my Cypher query:

```
WITH childD, dg, rdgd, u, ru, weight, totalVotes , criterionCoefficientSum  ORDER BY  weight / criterionCoefficientSum DESC, childD.createdAt DESC 
SKIP 0 LIMIT 10 
OPTIONAL MATCH (jobable:Profile {id: $profileId})  
RETURN childD AS decision, dg, rdgd, u, ru, weight, totalVotes, 
[(jobable)-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c1:Criterion)<-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) | {criterion: c1, relationship: vg1} ] AS jobableWeightedCriteria , 
[(jobable)-[:HAS_VOTE_ON]->(c1:Criterion)<-[vg1:HAS_VOTE_ON]-(childD) | {criterion: c1, relationship: vg1} ] AS weightedCriteria
```

I'm asking about the following line:

```
OPTIONAL MATCH (jobable:Profile {id: $profileId})
```

As you may see from the screenshot below:

[image]

Neo4j does 100k DB hits for that node. I need `jobable` node in order to use it in pattern comprehension in the return statement.
Please suggest how to reduce DB hits in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an index on the `id` attribute of the `Profile` nodes. Since currently the execution stage is `NodeByLabelScan`, and it is giving around 100K nodes, creating an index will replace `NodeByLabelScan`, with some index-based stage and your OPTIONAL MATCH will take less than 1k db hits.

```
CREATE INDEX id_index IF NOT EXISTS
FOR (n:Profile)
ON (n.id)
```